# not in clause, is there a better way

Tags: sql, monetdb

I am trying to exclude id numbers that have been seen before, my query is

```
select id from table1 where date1 >= eDate1 and date1 <= eDate2 and zId = 256
and id no in
(select id from table1 where date1 < eDate1 and zId = 256)
```

MonetDB.

Is there a better way, I am trying to simply exclude any id number that has been seen in the zone before the selected date range?

Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: "better way"?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Better performance, faster query.  Sorry is that was unclear Gordon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some database optimizers can deal with a large id list, other don't handle it well.

The best approach is to use a left join and filter on misses:

```
select a.id
from table1 a
left join table1 b on a.id = b.id and b.date1 < eDate1
where a.date1 between eDate1 and eDate2
and zId = 256
and b.id is null
```

Comment: I just read this and it states that 'That's why the LEFT JOIN / IS NULL query takes 810 ms, or 3 times as much as the NOT EXISTS / NOT IN query.' https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: @flavour404 depends on the size of the list. If it's big, this query should be faster. Also note that you need an index on the `id` column